# How to map web path to actual php file in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I implemented one php file to validate the OTP in wordpress. File is in the three levels down in the sub folder. But i want to access this php file as service and accessible on root context.

Please let me know if i required to do few configuration.

Comment: What is a problem ? you should mention the problem you are having , what you have attempted and what is a error, you should not only specify just what you want , tell us what you have attempted.

Comment: my php file is at the location public_html/registration/PHPMailer-master/examples/signup.php .  But from the website, i am able to access it directly  http://test.com/signup.php. My question is "Any configuration required for this".